# Zoom buttons in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, topojson

I have implemented a map in D3. I now want to add zoom buttons to zoom in and out of the map, something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/jfmmm/f5c62bc056e557b80447)

My implementation:

```html
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="topojson.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="zoomBtn">
    <input class="zoomBtn" rel="out" type="button" value="-" />
    <input class="zoomBtn" rel="in" type="button" value="+" />
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<style>
    #zoomBtn{ position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; }
    #map{ width: 960px; height: 500px; }
</style>
<script>
    var PHM = (function() {
     var options = {
      mapScope: 'states',
      minZoomLevel: 1,
      maxZoomLevel: 8
     };

     var svg, g, projection, path, zoom, mapFeatures;
     var width, height;

     function initMap() {
      width = $('#map').width();
      height = $('#map').height();

      d3.json("states.json", function(json) {
       //the svg element
       svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

       g = svg.append("g");
      
       projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .translate([-1000,700])
        .scale(1000);
       
       mapFeatures = topojson.feature(json, json.objects[(options.mapScope == 'world') ? 'world' : 'india']);

       
       var mapItems = g.selectAll("g").data(mapFeatures.features);

       path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

       var b = path.bounds(mapFeatures);

       var scale = .90 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height);
       var translate = [(width - scale * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - scale * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

    projection
        .scale(scale)
        .translate(translate);

       mapItems.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "country")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("id", function(d,i) { return d.id; })
        .attr("title", function(d,i) { return d.properties.name; })
        .style('stroke-width', 1)
        .style('stroke', '#ccc');

       d3.behavior.zoom();
       zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([options.minZoomLevel, options.maxZoomLevel])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

       svg.call(zoom).call(zoom.event);
      });
     }

     function initApp() {
      initMap();
      initAppControls();
     }

     function initAppControls() {
      $('.zoomBtn').on('click', function(e){
       zoomBtn($(this).attr('rel'));
       e.preventDefault();
      })
     }

     function zoomBtn(action) {
      var currentZoom = zoom.scale();
    
      if( action == 'in' ){
       if(currentZoom < options.maxZoomLevel){
        var newScale = Math.floor(currentZoom) + 1;
    
        var b = path.bounds(mapFeatures);
        var t = [(width - newScale * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - newScale * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];
    
        console.log(newScale);
        console.log(t);
        zoom.scale(newScale)
         .translate(t)
         .event(svg);
       }
      }else{
       if(currentZoom > options.minZoomLevel){
        var newScale = Math.floor(currentZoom) - 1;
    
        var b = path.bounds(mapFeatures);
        var t = [(width - newScale * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - newScale * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];
    
        console.log(newScale);
        console.log(t);
        zoom.scale(newScale)
         .translate(t)
         .event(svg);
       }
      }
     }
 
     return {
      init: function(){
       initApp();
      }
     }
    })();

   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**states.json** is the local json file containing the data about the map.
All the included js fiiles are present locally.

I have tried hosting the code. It still doesn't work so the problem lies somewhere else!

But this does not render the map at all. Just the zoom buttons are shown.

Comment: Where is your `states.json` coming from? A local file? Also, what kind of errors do you get?

Comment: @BDD yes **states.json** is a local file. No errors are shown but the map is not rendered!

Comment: Are you running node or are you just opening up the index.html file to try to view the data?

Comment: @BDD I am using firefox to open the html file. All the included js files are present in the local directory

Comment: So I've had a problem similar to this in the past. Try hosting your d3 code and see if you can get the JSON to appear. I'm not sure what the actual problem is, but I don't think d3 can render straight off of the HTML file like that. Someone else might be able to elaborate more

Comment: @BDD I have been implementing d3 for quite sometime like this but never before faced this problem. Anyway I will try it!

Comment: Yeah, give it a shot. I know I encountered it when I first started with d3, so maybe that's it. If not, we'll look for something else!

Comment: @BDD is right, you need to put it on a server to be able to load your data. Another very wide-spread error in implementations using asynchronous requests is to be found in the callback you provided to `d3.json()`. According to the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json): *the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the parsed JSON. The parsed JSON is undefined if an error occurs.* So, you are missing the second parameter, which will contain your data once the requests succeeds.

Comment: @BDD Tried your way it didn't work!

Comment: If you want to set it up in a fiddle, we can move our conversation to [a chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92277/zoom-buttons-in-d3) to further troubleshoot.

Comment: @BDD alas i don't have 20 rep